# How do you get all the links from a page with node puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm trying to build a web crawler with node and came across the puppeteer package which looks perfect for what I want. My end result is to gather all the links from a page, all of its text content, and then a screenshot of the page itself.

I ran the following and it appears to gather a large number of links, however on actual inspection of the site there are links that it is not gathering.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

module.exports = () => {
  (async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://pixabay.com/en/columbine-columbines-aquilegia-3379045/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'myscreenshot.png', fullPage: true });
    let text = await page.$eval('*', el => el.innerText.split(' '));
    text = text.map(string => {
      return string.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
    });

      let hrefs = await page.evaluate(() => {
          const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'))
          return links.map(link => link.href);
      });
    console.log('done');

    await browser.close();
  })();
};
```

for example this link : `/go/?t=image-details-shutterstock&amp;id=699165328` is nowhere in the array of hrefs. What's worse is these are links that lead out of the site, the exact type of thing I want to do, otherwise I'm stuck only crawling the one site.

Is there a reason my script is only showing some of the links? is the querySelector too narrow or rejecting certain links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That links are generated by `onclick` event, it saved in `data-go` attribute, for example

```
<a data-go="image-details-shutterstock&amp;id=458320033">
```

It only need to prepend `/go/?t=` and to get it

```
return links.map(link => link.href || link.getAttribute('data-go'));
```

there are also empty link for menu like

```
<a><i class="icon icon_menu_user"></i></a>
```